# How to delete a folder by using its contents as a reference?

Tags: python

I need to delete a folder and its contents, and while the contents are consistent, the folder name has no pattern with which to fall on. In the path defined in the below code, another folder exists, and *that* folder always has a file with extension ".cax":

```
import os
myfile_path = "H:/PythonTools/test/exampleA"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myfile_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".cax"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

This code successfully finds my file. How would I then go about deleting the folder it is in without listing the folder's name.

Comment: Your code seems to know the folder (`root`); why can't you use that?

Comment: @BryanOakley That was surprisingly easy. Thank you. I simply used `shutil.rmtree(root)` in place of the `print` statement and the folder was removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by @BryanOakley was simple. The following use of `shutil.rmtree(root)` solved my problem.

```
import os
import shutil
myfile_path = "H:/PythonTools/test/exampleA"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myfile_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".cax"):
            shutil.rmtree(root)
```